# Comparing from two different tables mySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a mySQL database where I want to take values(field1) from one table(tableA) and values(Field 2) from another table(tableB) then compare them. If Field 1 from table A is found in tableB Field 2 it should exclude them in my selection.

```
SELECT task_name, tasks.task_id
FROM tasks
INNER JOIN custom_fields_values ON value_object_id <>task_id
```

This is what I have tried but it doesn't seem to work. It displays the task_id in triplicate, which is odd.  Value_object_id has only two fields 24, and 32.  task_id has numbers 1-40, basically I need a list of 1-40 without field value 24 and 32.

```
SELECT task_name, tasks.task_id
FROM tasks
INNER JOIN custom_fields_values ON value_object_id =task_id
```

This however works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're using an `INNER JOIN` -- try using a `LEFT JOIN` instead.

```
SELECT tasks.task_name, tasks.task_id
FROM tasks
LEFT JOIN custom_fields_values ON custom_fields_values.value_object_id=tasks.task_id
WHERE custom_fields_values.value_object_id IS NULL
```

Good luck.

Comment: This worked Thank you! I figured it was something simple I was over looking, I'll upvote in 5 min. (Timer)

Answer (score 1):

You need an **[anti-semijoin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Antijoin_.28.E2.96.B7.29)**:

```
SELECT task_name, task_id
FROM tasks AS t
WHERE NOT EXISTS
      ( SELECT *
        FROM custom_fields_values AS c
        WHERE c.value_object_id = t.task_id
      ) ;
```